# iOS 14. requestAuthorizationForAccessLevel for PHAccessLevelAddOnly still show "Select Photos..." for save image in Photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, photo, ios14

I want to save the image to Photos without showing "Select Photos ...", and choose a save method by specifying **PHAccessLevelAddOnly**. But I still see "Select Photos ..." in the selection options. Why might this be happening?

```
PHAuthorizationStatus prevStatus = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];

if (@available(iOS 14, *)) {
    prevStatus = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatusForAccessLevel:PHAccessLevelAddOnly];

    if (prevStatus == PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorizationForAccessLevel:(PHAccessLevelAddOnly) handler:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
            if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    ...
                });
            }
        }];
        return;
    }
}
```

Xcode Version 12.0 beta 6 (12A8189n)

Comment: requestAuthorizationForAccessLevel causes a message to be shown to gain access, what happens next doesn't matter.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue when using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_:_:_:_)` so I switched to using `PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from:)` but still get the same issue.

From what I can see, this is a bug because the `requestAuthorizationForAccessLevel` block/closure is actually being executed twice. This is in the GM seed as well :/

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, I just forgot to set the key in info.plist - NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription.

Comment: OK, but the fact that you then did not crash is a bug and you should report it.

Comment: There is ` <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key><string>asdf</string>` in info.plist but I still got error